# CSS of footer stops working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Today i noticed on one of my websites, the footer css was gone. I tried to load the page on mozilla and explorer and it showed up fine. I did not change anything on the css since last month. It just randomly dissapeared on chrome or it doesn't show up anymore.

you can see it for yourself at: http://www.d-dayinfo.org/

I use php so my footer is one single file wich is displayed (included) on all the other pages.
Anyone who have had the same experience with google chrome and would like to help me out?

Really don't know what to do

Comment: Open up "Developer Tools" and look at the errors there.  There are several `404` returned from the server.

Comment: Same remark, fix your issues first and try to copy your code to a JSFiddle-like so you we can easily check what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Thomas! Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, rather than a general "come help me with my code" site. If you could do a bit more work yourself (i.e. isolate the problem code into its own file) and detail that here, you'd be more likely to get good answers.

Comment: Also, the footer shows up fine here in Chrome...

Comment: there? Did you check my Answer? is that works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem on line number **1812** of [**styles.css**](http://www.d-dayinfo.org/styles.css)

```
@-webkit-keyframes smallToBig { from-webkit-transform: scale(0.1); }
to { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
{  }
@-moz-keyframes smallToBig { from-moz-transform: scale(0.1); }
to { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
 {  }
@-ms-keyframes smallToBig { from-ms-transform: scale(0.1); }
to { -ms-transform: scale(1); }
{  }
@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom { from-webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
to { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
{  }
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom { from-moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
to { -moz-transform: translateY(0%); }
{  }
@-ms-keyframes moveFromBottom { from-ms-transform: translateY(100%); }
to { -ms-transform: translateY(0%); }
{  }
```

something is wrong here please make this correct its conflict CHROME with CSS chrome

IS should like

```
@-webkit-keyframes smallToBig { 
    from{-webkit-transform: scale(0.1); }
    to { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}
@-moz-keyframes smallToBig { 
    from{ -moz-transform: scale(0.1); }
    to { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}
@-ms-keyframes smallToBig { 
    from{ -ms-transform: scale(0.1); }
    to { -ms-transform: scale(1); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom { 
    from{ -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from{ -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
    to { -moz-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
@-ms-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from{ -ms-transform: translateY(100%); }
    to { -ms-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
```

Comment: also same problem, css syntax at 1919 line

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. 

It's probably Chrome which has updated the validation for css somehow. I read about it in a discussion on google forums that google is tightening the approval for the CSS. Because 2 weeks ago the footer showed up just fine.

But thanks for the adjustment, it worked for me!

Comment: then please select my answer as useful and up-vote me to you that help's me.